# Web View with form post

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight 6.2 for building hybrid application.I need to do integration with payment gateway.For that i need to post data through my html form.I am able to hit the server with action in html and the payment gateway opens in my mobile.

Now the problem is once the gateway page opens.I am not able to go back to my application .I did every possible way to override this.I think the payment gateway is secured and back button is disabled in their server pages.

I am newbie to IBM Worklight .Kindly help me resolving this..For Information code is mentioned below..

```
<form class="form"  action="http://example.com/"  method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="checksum" id="checksum"> 
                    <input type="submit" value ="Pay Now">
</form>
```

Somebody suggested me using Webview...but i am not sure how to use Web view..
Also I cannot use Jquery AJAX Call.The only way is to submit the form..

Kindly bear with me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To open another webview, you can follow the sample provided as part of the following tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/advanced-topics/integrating-server-generated-pages-hybrid-applications/

Basically you use a Cordova plug-in to open another webview ontop of your application.

You may also consider using Corodva InAppBrowser: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html

Cordova is built-into Worklight, so you need only to use its APIs. No configuration needed.

Comment: Hi Idan Thanks for your answer but I cannot use window.open because with that i cannot pass my form data..and with web server pages it is not working.I am only allowed to submit the form with action.As mentioned i am not allowed to even hit there server with AJAX call

Comment: @Dss did you find the solution? I am also facing the same issue. window.open is not working if I pass form data with method = post